# c++ Functions that call virtual functions inside

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Have been trying to develop a better understanding of virtual functions. For the sake of argument, say I have a base class:

```
class Shape
{
protected:
    string _name;
    int _num;
public:
    Shape();
    virtual double CalcShape();
};
```

And 2 lower classes:

```
class Rectangle : public Shape
{
private:
    double _height;
    double _width;
public:
    Rectangle();
    Rectangle(double, double);
    double GetHeight();
    double GetWidth();
    double CalcShape(double, double); //calculates rectangle
};

class Triangle : public Shape
{
private:
    double _side1;
    double _side2;
    double _side3;
public:
    Triangle();
    Triangle(double, double, double);
    double GetSide();
    double CalcShape(double, double, double); //calculates triangle
};
```

Say I also have a function called `ShowCalc(Shape&);`. This function calls the `CalcShape()` function inside.

```
void ShowCalc(Shape& sh)
{
    return sh.CalcShape(); 
}
```

Now is there a way to get this function `CalcShape()` to accept input of both the Triangle's `GetSide()` function and the Rectangle's `GetHeight()` and `GetWidth()` seeing as how Triangle takes 3 parameters and Rectangle takes 2?

Comment: Just get rid of the parameters. `CalcShape` doesn't need them, they're already member variables.

Comment: @PeterWood: Unless that function is really the setter (`CalcShape(2,4)` could mean in some weird design: `setWidthHeight(2,4)`)

Answer (score 2):

I see multiple design errors here:

- you can't use `virtual` method with references: a reference points to a real object of that specified type. Dynamic dispatch doesn't work because `Shape&` is a `Shape` and even if you assign a children class to it when initializing the value, everything that is derived is discarded because of [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).
- `virtual` functions are meant to be used when overridden methods in subclasses have a specific implementation. An overridden method has the same signature of the original method. In your case you have `CalcShape(void)` in `Shape` and `CalcShape(double, double)` in `Rectangle`. This is not **overriding**, this is **overloading** which is a complete different thing. You can take advance of `override` keyword in C++11 to be sure you are correctly overriding virtual methods.
- `virtual` methods should be pure if the implementation on base class makes no sense (since you can't compute the area of an unknown type shape). If you had this pure ( `= 0` ) the compiler would have warned you about the fact that none of children classes are actually overriding it.

To obtain what you want you need to use the member variables in the implementation, not pass them through the call, eg:

```
class Shape {
  virtual double calcArea() = 0;
}

class Rectangle : public Shape {
  private: 
    double width, height;
  public:
    virtual double calcArea() override { return width*height; }
}

Shape *shape = new Rectangle(10,20);
double area = shape->calcArea();
```

Comment: Ah, so if I wanted to override a method in a child class, they must have the same parameters? I like this override keyword in this case though.

Comment: The fact is that it's an override just when it replaces the implementation of the ancestor class. To replace it, it must have the same name and the same arguments. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding. In the wikipedia page there is an example in C++ which is rather similar to yours, too.